# Query To Compare Data

Tags: sql-server, query

I'm trying to build a query to show rows in a Customer table that match rows exactly in 2 columns (Address 1 and Address 2) but then show only if a 3rd column is not matching.

```
Customer ID Status  Address 1 Address 2
----------  ------ ---------- ----------
    2        Free   1 Main St. Apt 2
    3        Paid   1 Main St. Apt 2
    5        Free   2 Main St. Apt 1
    7        Free   2 Main St. Apt 1
```

So in the above data example I would want the query to only show that Customer IDs 2 and 3 match on Address 1 and Address 2 but do not match by Status. It would be like an exception report showing those data matches. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17277.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the table with itself:

```
SELECT c1.CustomerID, c1.Status, c2.CustomerID, c2.Status
  FROM Customers AS c1
  INNER JOIN Customers AS c2
    ON c1.Address1   =  c2.Address1
  AND (c1.Address2   =  c2.Address2 OR (c1.Address2 IS NULL AND
                                        c2.Address2 IS NULL))
   AND c1.Status     != c2.Status
   AND c1.CustomerID <  c2.CustomerID
```

The last line makes sure you don't get duplicate rows (unless there are *more* than two customers on the same address).

As suggested in the comments by [Nick Roz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/101113/nick-roz), some fields could be `NULL`. Since `NULL != NULL`, you need to check specifically for those cases. In the query, I assumed `CustomerID`, `Status` and `Address1` are never `NULL`, but `Address2` can be.

Answer (score 2):

I think `EXISTS` is the simplest solution, since it handles NULL values correctly and the query plan is a simple semi-join.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE
      (
          CustomerID INT,
          Status VARCHAR(50),
          Address1 VARCHAR(50),
          Address2 VARCHAR(50)
      );

INSERT INTO @tmp
VALUES ( 2, 'Free', '1 Main St.', 'Apt 2' ),
       ( 3, 'Paid', '1 Main St.', 'Apt 2' ),
       ( 5, 'Free', '2 Main St.', 'Apt 1' ),
       ( 7, 'Free', '2 Main St.', 'Apt 1' );


SELECT *
FROM @tmp AS t
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1/0
FROM @tmp AS t2
WHERE t.Address1 = t2.Address1
AND   t.Address2 = t2.Address2
AND   t.Status <> t2.Status
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify different `status` values using `group by` on `Address1` and  `Address2` columns and checking if max and min values for `status` are different.

Then you can join this dataset to the original data to retrieve only the lines that have same `Address1`, `Address2`, but different `status`.

```
declare @tmp table(CustomerID int, [Status] varchar(50), 
                   Address1 varchar(50), Address2 varchar(50))

insert into @tmp values
     (2, 'Free','1 Main St.','Apt 2')
    ,(3, 'Paid','1 Main St.','Apt 2')
    ,(5, 'Free','2 Main St.','Apt 1')
    ,(7, 'Free','2 Main St.','Apt 1')

select t1.* 
from @tmp t1
inner join 
(
    select Address1, Address2
    from @tmp 
    group by Address1, Address2
    having min(isnull([Status],'')) <> max(isnull([Status],''))
) err
on t1.Address1 = err.Address1 
    and 
   t1.Address2 = err.Address2
```

Results:

[image]